# Shell script to extract app name

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, jenkins

I have Repo_URLs in Jenkins for various jobs which looks like:

```
ssh://git@stash.dev-company.net:7999/sad/agreement-edge.git
ssh://git@stash.dev-company.net:7999/che/agreement-middle.git
ssh://git@stash.dev-company.net:7999/char/login-edge.git
```

I need to extract **agreement-edge,agreement-middle,login-edge** from it.

Lets say Repo url is set as a variable

RepoEndpoint=ssh://git@stash.dev-company.net:7999/sad/agreement-edge.git

How do i extract agreement-edge out of it?

Comment: With sed: `echo "$RepoEndpoint" | sed 's|.*/||;s|\..*||'`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With bash's [Parameter Expansion](http://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#SEC32) :

```
RepoEndpoint="ssh://git@stash.dev-company.net:7999/sad/agreement-edge.git"
RepoEndpoint="${RepoEndpoint%.*}"
RepoEndpoint="${RepoEndpoint##*/}"
echo "$RepoEndpoint"
```

Output:

```
agreement-edge
```

Comment: I dont need the .git in the end

Answer (score 2):

`sed` version, that you can run on a file (if you have multiple lines to process):

```
sed 's=.*/\(.*\).git$=\1=' file_name
```

or directly on the string:

```
sed 's=.*/\(.*\).git$=\1=' <<< 'ssh://git@stash.dev-company.net:7999/sad/agreement-edge.git'
```

… or with a variable:

```
sed 's=.*/\(.*\).git$=\1=' <<< "$RepoEndPoint"
```